# How can I assure that a slot is executed in a specific thread's context?

Tags: c++, qt

Suppose that I have a thread A where a signal X is emitted and also a thread B which has the slot Y that the signal X is connected to. Should I be still concerned if slot Y is being executed in thread A's context? Or would it be executed in thread B's context as I assumed?

Comment: you can try it out. [std::this_thread::get_id()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id) will tell you in which thread you are

Comment: In my projects I use boost::asio and then in the signal handler, `dispatch` to the correct `io_service` or `strand`. The thread of execution is then deterministic.

Comment: [Signals and Slots Across Threads](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be concerned. This is the purpose of the 5th parameter in `QObject::connect`.

If you do this:

```
connect(A,X,B,Y,Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Then `A` will just call `Y()` from its own thread. However, if you do this:

```
connect(A,X,B,Y,Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

`A` will add `Y()` to `B`'s event queue, and `B` will execute `Y()` later in its own thread.

More information about this [can be found here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html).

Comment: Important to note, if you omit the last argument, if A and B are in 2 different threads the second version will be used, if they are in the same thread the first version will be used instead

Comment: So I don't have to use 5th parameter in connect(), it will automatically select the correct one?

Comment: @fatma.ekici Yes. However, I prefer to mention it explicitly when in doubt.

Comment: It is not very clear as op called the threads A and B, but you use them as QObjects in your example. The owner of the slot, the class instance, is not necessary the QThread object, and actually should not be : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details